# Query for simple table

Tags: sql

I have to write a query for available cars in base below.

[image]

I tried this:

```
select * 
from [Rental] 
where [Rental].RentEndDate is not null
```

[image]

But it shows an already rented car—`CarID 5` shouldn't be available to rent. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
Select * from Rental r where r.rentenddate is not null
and not exists ( select 1 from rental r1 where r1.carid = r.carid and r1.rentenddate is null )
```

First it is checking all car who is not on rent. Then there is possibility the car is returned and again rented. So to get only cars who is available, is achieved by adding not exists(query_to_search_car_is_on_rent) clause.

Comment: you can mark an answer as correct. so that other people can be benefited.

Answer (score 0):

You should retrieve the cars where only startdate is present.

```
Select * from Rental where rentenddate is null.
```

Comment: if the rentdate is null , this car is not returnted yet.